# SQL Join with session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a website using asp.net and C# that stores `Session["ID"]`

I have two different tables that look like this:

**Foo**
ID
BarID

**Bar**
BarID
Name
Code

I want to have an SQL command that selects the Name and Code from the **Bar** table that has the same ID as the session.

The code I've tried is this:

```
OleDbConnection conn;
conn = new OleDbConnection(.....);
OleDbCommand comm;
OleDbDataReader reader;
comm = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Bar.Name, Bar.Code, Foo.ID FROM Bar JOIN Foo ON Foo.BarID = Bar.BarID WHERE Foo.ID = @ID", conn);
comm.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer);
comm.Parameters["@ID"].Value = Session["ID"].ToString();

conn.Open();
reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
```

I've updated the answer but I'm still running into the same problem. Is this because I'm checking the statement with `reader = comm.ExecuteReader();` ? Is there a better way to do it?

The error I get is:

> **Syntax error in FROM clause.**
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: Change query to `SELECT Bar.Name, Bar.Code, Foo.ID FROM Bar JOIN Foo Where Foo.ID = @ID`

Answer (score 2):

Fo some reason your conditions on `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses merged. Here is the correct version:

```
SELECT Bar.Name, Bar.Code, Foo.ID
FROM Bar
JOIN Foo ON Foo.BarID = Bar.BarID
WHERE Foo.ID = @ID
```

Comment: Updated the question with this but still running into the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT Bar.Name, Bar.Code, Foo.ID FROM Bar JOIN Bar ON Foo.ID = @ID"
```

Should be

```
"SELECT Bar.Name, Bar.Code, Foo.ID FROM Bar JOIN Foo ON Foo.BarID = Bar.BarID WHERE Foo.Id = @ID"
```

You were selecting from Bar and then joining to Bar. You actually want to join to Foo.

For your edit:

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer);
comm.Parameters["@ID"].Value = (int) Session["ID"];
```

The parameter wants an integer but you're giving it a string.

Comment: I saw that, too, but I doubt those are actually table names. It's more likely he just got that part wrong when anonymizing his tables.

Comment: Even if that is the case the query was still wrong. Needs the where if he wants to select by id.

Comment: Updated question with this code but still running into problems

Comment: What is the issue specifically? Are you getting an exception? No records returned?

Comment: This update gives another error on this row instead. I know the code I'm using is working as I have it several other places where it works as it should

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure you're replacing your table names with Foo and Bar for your question but are your actual table and field names reserved words? Have you tried to wrap your table and field names with brackets []?

Comment: Double-checked now for the reserved words in both C# and SQL and I don't use any of them

Comment: Again, I'm sure it's just an inconsistency between your question and actual code but your OleDbConnection is named 'conn' but you pass 'connect' into the command. Is there another connection object that might be causing the issue? I've exhausted my knowledge on this topic but I'm going to keep thinking. I'll delete answer in a bit if I have nothing else. I don't know if you can but it wouldn't hurt to post actual table and field names.